# Laravel Authentication - User can not login even the credentials are right and exactly the same from the database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a new project and after creating all the needed modules for the authentication of the system, I cannot log in and go to the right page and it always redirects to login page even though the login credentials are right and exactly the same from the database. Here are the codes. Please help me to know exactly what and where did I go wrong, thank you in advance.

> Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    function index() {
        return view('auth/login');
    }

    function checklogin(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required|min:6'
        ]);

        $user_data = array(
            'username'=>$request->get('username'),
            'password'=>$request->get('password')
        );

        if(Auth::attempt($user_data)) {
            return redirect('personnel');
        }else {
            return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
        }
    }

    function successlogin() {
        return view('personnel');
    }

    function logout() {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('auth');
    }
}
```

> **login.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.general-master')

@section('title', 'Login')

@section('content')
<div class="header align-left general-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>
<div class="body">
    @if(isset(Auth::user()->username))
        <script>window.location = "/personnel";</script>
    @endif

    @if($message = Session::get('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </div>
    @endif

    @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/checklogin') }}">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="username" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }} general-input" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>

                @if ($errors->has('username'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }} general-input" name="password" required>

                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-2">
                <div class="form-check">
                    &emsp;&emsp;
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
                &emsp;
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ __('Login') }}
                </button>

                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                    <a class="btn btn-primary col-white" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                    </a>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

> **person.blade.php -- this is the right page to go after logging in**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Personnel Management')

@section('content')
    @if(isset(Auth::user()->username))
        <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="block-header">
                    <h2 class="align-center">
                        PERSONNEL MANAGEMENT
                    </h2>
                </div>            

                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="header">
                                <button type="button" class="btn bg-blue waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPersonnelModal">
                                    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
                                    <span>ADD PERSONNEL</span>
                                </button>
                                <input type="text" id="txtSearchPerKey" name="txtSearchPerKey">
                                <span id="spanSearchPerKey">Search: </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="tblViewPersonnels" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="align-center">Name</th>
                                                <th class="align-center">Position</th>
                                                <th class="align-center">Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="align-center">Name</th>
                                                <th class="align-center">Position</th>
                                                <th class="align-center">Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <!-- code will be generated here -->
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    else
        <script>window.location = "/auth";</script>
    @endif
@endsection
```

> **web.php -- here are the routes**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

> **LOGIN**

```
Route::get('/auth', 'AuthController@index');
Route::post('/auth/checklogin', 'AuthController@checklogin');
Route::get('/auth/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
```

> **PERSONNEL**

```
Route::get('/personnel', function () {
    return view('personnel');
});
```

Comment: are you using `email` or `username` in your database as the credential?

Comment: I'm using username

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `username` column instead of laravel's default `email` column,

try doing it this way :

```
if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $request['username'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
   return redirect('personnel');
}else {
    return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
}
```

Comment: should it only be the code inside the checklogin function?

Comment: yep, if it still doesn't work. please share the error

Comment: here is the [link](https://res.cloudinary.com/dprwhbrhz/image/upload/v1544845040/picture1.png) for a screenshot that displays "wrong login details" but the credential that I have entered are correct

Comment: can you show how you save the credentials in the database?

Comment: I'm just currently saving credentials in the database manually and there is no code for it yet

Comment: so the password isn't hashed? `Auth::attempt` automatically compares your password to its hashed form. If you want to try your login, use this data in your password column `$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm` it's unhashed value is `secret`

Comment: thanks for the response, much appreciated but I've already make a new auth in cmd and there is also a new problem about "Attribute [controllers] does not exist." in cmd when I'm creating a new users table

Comment: yes, here is another [link](https://res.cloudinary.com/dprwhbrhz/image/upload/v1544854362/error.png) for the screenshot

Comment: why did that error come up? maybe you should ask it in a new post since if it is different from your login error.

Comment: no need for another question, it's because of this code I copied online => Route::controllers([
   'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]); it's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

For this type of error your only check your fields names and the table connection as it right or not it not a big issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you need to use bcrypt method when reading the user's password

```
$user_data = array(
      'username'=>$request->get('username'),
      'password'=>bcrypt($request->get('password'))
);
```

Laravel passwords are encrypted so you can't compare the user's password without encrypting it first. It will always return false.

Comment: When using `Auth::attempt`>You should not hash the password specified as the password value, since the framework will automatically hash the value before comparing it to the hashed password in the database.